# android settext for textview from relative weakreference

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, weak-references

I have an Activity and an inner class with name `InnerClass` in it which its `updateAfterDelay()` method must update a `TextView` . I want to avoid memory leak. So I changed `InnerClass` to static and try to use `WeakReference` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.main );

        textView = (TextView) findViewById ( R.id.textView );
    }

    private static class InnerClass {

        private final WeakReference<TextView> targetTextView;

        public InnerClass(TextView targetTextView) {
            this.targetTextView = new WeakReference<TextView> ( targetTextView );
        }

        void updateAfterDelay() {
            targetTextView.setText ( "text" );
        }

    }

}
```

But on `targetTextView.setText ( "text" );` I get this compile error:

```
cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String)'
```

How I can solve above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be `targetTextView.get().setText("")`.

Answer (score 1):

Get TextView and set text.

```
targetTextView.get().setText ( "text" );
```